# SQL update command and table locking

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

i have an SQL table and VB.NET application.
the application loads the sql table to a datatable then it starts updating data to records by fetching some websites, it takes an average of 1.4 sec to fill datatable row with new data.

now i was wondering if its ok to use the sql update command to update a single record in the sql table and run it every time a record is updated which means run the update command for a single record every 1.4 sec

problem is other applications use this table in the same time and one of them writes to the same table but other columns,will the table get locked for other applications during this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL won't lock the table by default, but you probably should lock the table while updating it to prevent data corruption if those apps are doing alterations. performance will take a small hit, yes, but better that than having to rebuild it because it got messed up. this is a good explanation of locking

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84509/managing-database-locks-in-sql-server/

if the other applications are just querying the table while you're updating, there shouldn't be any impact BUT they might get some odd results if they query it mid-update. locking is mainly about the risk of 2 people modifying the same record at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out why it takes 1.4 second to update a single record. Chances are it's because VB.NET needs to do some processing (while it's `fetching some websites`). For example, it could be taking you 1.3 seconds to perform necessary calculations (client time), and 0.1 second to update a single record (server time). In this case, you could perform update in batches, to minimize database access time.

Table will get locked, but only for a short time, so you don't need to worry about that, in general.

Comment: 1.4 i really reasonable time since it has to fetch alot of data from multiple websites, considering page load time

Comment: @user1570048: No problem. Point was that with update batches, you should be able to minimize overall table lock time.